# Server-push or client-request? TCP or UDP?

Tags: java, tcp, udp, socket.io

I'd like to implement a function of realtime message such as chatting in facebook but several questions confuse me:
1. To reduce overhead of server and make it really 'realtime', I should use a full-duplex way of communication like socket instead of Ajax, is that right?
2. If I use socket, which protocol should I choose, TCP or UDP?
3. Assuming that I am using TCP, will server keep trying to resend the lost packages so that it would take much overhead?
4. What if the network failed in a communication between server and a client? Will the socket close it self or I should handle with several kinds of network conditions?
Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest you try TCP and find out.  You could be trying to solve problems which won't b an issue for you. :)

Comment: I just have no idea about how to handle different network conditions. Thanks for your advice, I will try. :)

Comment: Almost all errors result in an IOException.  If you attempt to read() from a connection you will be able to detect the connection has been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use WebSockets. XMLHttpRequest is probably obsolete now for anything real-time (because it's not real-time), though you could fall back to using it for people who use a browser that doesn't support WebSockets
2. - Use UDP if the information you are sending is only valid for the time it is sent, for example in games that would be the position of the players (you don't care to receive the position they were in 5 seconds ago). Besides, you can't use UDP with WebSockets
   - For anything other than that, use TCP (unless you do hole punching to achieve p2p), because loss of data is probably bad for you, and TCP handles that.
3. You would have to check for and resend lost data manually with UDP anyway, unless failure in communication is acceptable by you
4. You will get an IOException. If the connection was closed improperly the exception will be thrown after a timeout of unresponsiveness that you are able to change according to your needs. This is assuming you use TCP, otherwise you should figure out yourself when you consider clients connected or disconnected according to the responses/data you receive (or not receive).

Comment: It's very useful of your explaination. But still, will TCP itself keep trying to resend data packets because of none response from client? Another question, if UDP is used in transfering an image, can the image be shown (not very accurate though) at client when some of data packets lost during delivering?

Comment: If this level of TCP is interesting you, then you should read [RFC 793 - Transmission Control Protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt)